# Visual Studio Code / Debugger / Raspberry PI Unable to start debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I'm getting this error message from Visual Studio Code when I attempt to run remote debugging (see large screenshot below)

I know this is a version mismatch - but with Visual Studio on 7.0.2, the PI latest version is 6.0.405.

From this screenshot, its saying that version 7.0.2 is not installed - but that version (as far as I know and I've tried) is not available

I'm new to PI development, and I've researched this extensively.  I'm looking for what I'm clearly I am clearly missing to sync up the two versions and get the debugger to attach to a program running on the PI (which is running fine)

I have the environmental variable for DOTNET_ROOT set correctly, with the latest PI installation, and debugger installed as well
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what's the output of `dotnet --info`?

Comment: "but that version (as far as I know and I've tried) is not available" How did you test? [7.0.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) certainly is available.

Comment: As I'm new to this, I downloaded dotnet using a script I found which was pegged to net6 and hence miss match between the device and my PC.  Moved to VS (versus VS Code) and simply attached the debugger.  I also created a self contained package so all code required is in the directory.  Small steps in learning this world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `dotnet-install` script, that is for CI (continuous integration) only. To install dotnet on the Raspberry Pi, go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-download and download the binaries(!) for version 7.0.2 for Arm64 (assuming you already have the 64 bit version of Raspberry Pi OS installed).

The instructions on the download page will install the runtime only for the current user. I would recommend to install it globally (there's typically only one user on a Raspberry Pi, anyway). To do so, run these commands:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/dotnet
sudo tar zxf dotnet-sdk-7.0.102-linux-arm64.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

(setting `DOTNET_ROOT` is not necessary)

to verify proper installation, run

```
dotnet --info
```

When a new version becomes available (or you also need to install version 6.0 in parallel), just extract the package to the same directory. They can install side-by-side.